# How to get 12.6 with a=10.3 and b=2.3?

Tags: javascript

[Tried](http://jsfiddle.net/DYKJB/2/) :

```
var a=10.3;
var b=2.3;
alert(a+b);
```

but I get `12.600000000000001`. I know JavaScript is loosely typed, but I hope I can do a sum :)

Comment: so your question is about formatting a number with a limited number of decimals?

Comment: This inaccuracy is rather due to how [floating point numbers are represented in binary](http://www.google.com/search?What%20every%20computer%20scientist%20should%20know%20about%20floating-point%20arithmetic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply to the precision you want then round and divide by whatever you multiplied by:

```
var a=10.3;
var b=2.3;
alert(Math.round((a+b) * 10) / 10);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DYKJB/3/

Answer (score 2):

you can use toFixed() method also

```
var a=10.3;
var b=2.3;
alert((a+b).toFixed(1));​
```

Works in chrome

Answer (score 1):

It's not about the typing but about the [precision of floating point types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems). You need to round for presentation.

Floating point types are not a good choice if you need exact values. If you want to express currency values express them as cents or use an appropriate library for this.